# python3 , get a block of string between tokens

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```
txt='''
-------
xxx: 111111111
     222222222
------------
yyy: 11111
     222222222
------------
zzz: 333
------------
'''
```

python, import re. how to get sub string between '--------' ? for example get

```
yyy: 11111
     222222222
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import re

txt='''
-------
xxx: 111111111
     222222222
------------
yyy: 11111
     222222222
------------
zzz: 333
------------
'''

x  =  [x.strip() for x in re.split("[-]{1,}", txt) if x.strip()]
```

---

```
['xxx: 111111111\n     222222222', 'yyy: 11111\n     222222222', 'zzz: 333']
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/3198f16726)

Comment: I want result is 'yyy: 11111\n     222222222'. use re module

Answer (score 0):

```
txt='''
-------
xxx: 111111111
     222222222
------------
yyy: 11111
     222222222
------------
zzz: 333
------------
'''
import re
p=re.compile(r'yyy[\s\S]*?(?=----)')
m=p.search(txt)
print(m.group(0))
```